# Bootstrap login form text box overlap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've checked out some other answers for this but didn't work for me. Really puzzled by this one.

[image]

As you can see the right side overlaps the border. my .css for the box:

```
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
width: 100%;
padding: 12px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I tried using `max-width: 100%;` but it doesn't seem to chance it.

Code for the form:

```css
form {
border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}


img.avatar {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
     display: block;
     float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Login To Your Account</h2>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
      <label><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

      <button type="submit">Login</button>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your `input` CSS, but can you please provide the rest of the box, and the relevant HTML as well (to confirm your selector targets)? It's rather difficult to answer this question without it. It would help if you could update your question to list all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: Thanking you kindly. Just updated

Comment: This code works fine. Textbox is not going outside of div. In which browser do you have a problem..?

Comment: which bootstrap version you used? because in version-4 it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe add a width to the container.

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 16px;
}
```

this might fix it.

And then if that fails, you could also add a smaller width to the input textboxes:

```
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
width: 75%;
padding: 12px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I do not recommend using `!imporatant` but you could also try adding it to the width:

```
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
width: 75%!important;
padding: 12px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I just also noticed your login button is to overlapping. So you need to also add the above `width: 75%;` to the imput submit too. I do not see if you have a submit imput class you haven't posted it